# Cake 3.x How to use database sessions with a controller named SessionsController?

Tags: session, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

**Cake Version 3.1.2**

What I did:

1. Run the following query in MySQL database:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
     `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
     `data` BLOB, -- or BYTEA for PostgreSQL
     `expires` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
   );
   ```
2. Change `app.php`

   ```
   'Session' => [
       'defaults' => 'database',
   ],
   ```

What I wanted:

To have a `SessionsController.php`

so I can have :

- `/sessions/add` as the login page and action (allowing GET and POST)
- `/sessions/delete` as the logout page and action (allowing GET and DELETE)
- `/admin/sessions/delete` as a way for admin backend to logout certain users (allowing DELETE)
- `/admin/sessions/index` as a way to fetch all the sessions in a paginated way (allowing GET)

Questions in my mind:

1. Do I actually bake Session Entity and Table?
2. Do I actually bake Session Controller?
3. Is it even possible for me to have SessionsController even when I **don't** use database to handle my Session? How do I bake such a Controller that does not have a default Entity or Table?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the questions you have are answered in the [CakePHP Book](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/index.html). The answers to your questions are:

1. Do I actually bake Session Entity and Table?
2. Do I actually bake Session Controller?

   A: No, you don't HAVE to bake anything. You can write all the code by hand. Although, I recommend baking to set up the skeleton of the classes.
3. Is it even possible for me to have SessionsController even when I don't use database to handle my Session?

   A: Yes, you can name your  controllers anything you want as long as you follow the [naming conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html#controller-conventions).
4. How do I bake such a Controller that does not have a default Entity or Table?

   A: You just bake it. You don't have to use models, default or otherwise, in your controllers.